# Sudo asking for password of the postgres user

Tags: linux, postgresql, tcp

I'm trying to execute

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

Being a postgres user.
But then sudo asks for a password of a postgres user

```
[sudo] password for postgres:
```

Already tried to set `NOPASSWD: ALL` in sudoers, but it doesn't help.

Tried to change postgres user password using psql, but it doesn't help too.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Postgres. You need to differentiate between the system user `postgres` and the database user `postgres`. What you are dealing with here is the system user. Just use the sudo password you would use for your user name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed OS user postgres password

```
sudo bash
```

And then

```
passwd postgres
```

Comment: Careful! Changing the OS postgres user's password creates a security hazard. See https://serverfault.com/a/325596/179405